# How to Draw the ellipsoid using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Three.js only have functions that draw ellipses,but I want to draw the ellipsoid, please help me!

I want to draw the ellipsoid using three.js

Answer (score 2):

You can construct an ellipsoid by scaling a sphere:

```js
const ellipsoidGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 32, 16);
ellipsoidGeometry.rotateZ(Math.PI/2);
ellipsoidGeometry.scale(2, 1, 1);
const ellipsoidMesh = new THREE.Mesh(ellipsoidGeometry, yourMaterial);
```

[image]

Comment: @arbiterpan Of course you can. You can do anything you want with any other mesh or geometry. Note, you can change the scale and you can also scale the mesh.

Comment: ok,I have tried,It give me what I need,great!